# MySQL Grouping By and COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains the following columns:

UniqueID
remote_ip_addr
platform

I want to create a query, which basically shows each IP address just once from each platform and count how many distinct platform entries there are

```
SELECT platform, COUNT(platform) 
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform 
ORDER BY COUNT(platform) DESC
```

So for example from the following table:

```
uniqueID---remote_ip_addr----platform
1           20.15.1.234       iPhone
2           20.15.1.234       iPhone
3           20.15.1.234       iPhone
4           20.15.1.234       Android
5           20.15.1.234       Android
```

I'll get the following result:

```
platform----COUNT(platform)
iPhone          1
Android         1
```

Right now I get the following:

```
platform----COUNT(platform)
iPhone          3
Android         2
```

Because they're all the same ip, I want to get only 1 distinct value...

Thank you for your help.

edit: I should have mentioned that there's another field, which is called app_id.

So the table is more like:

```
uniqueID---remote_ip_addr----platform---app_id
1           20.15.1.234       iPhone      23
2           20.15.1.234       iPhone      23
3           20.15.1.234       iPhone      18
4           20.15.1.234       Android     24
5           20.15.1.234       Android     25
```

in this case, I want the result to be:

```
platform----COUNT(platform)
iPhone          2
Android         2
```

Thank you, and sorry because I didn't think it was relevant and now I see it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want for every platfrom, the number of distinct IP addresses. Then you can use this. Note the `COUNT`ing of `DICTINCT remote_ip_addr` for every (`GROUP BY`) platform:

```
SELECT platform
     , COUNT(DISTINCT remote_ip_addr) AS countDistinctIPaddresses
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform 
ORDER BY countDistinctIPaddresses DESC
```

---

After OP's update. (it's not good practise to alter the question by the way).

It's not clear if you want distinct app_ids for every platfrom:

```
SELECT platform
     , COUNT(DISTINCT app_id)
       AS cnt
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

or distinct combinations of (app_id,remote_ip_addr)s for every platfrom:

```
SELECT platform
     , COUNT(DISTINCT app_id, remote_ip_addr)
       AS cnt
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Depends on what the wanted result is, say if you had one more row:

```
uniqueID---remote_ip_addr----platform---app_id
6           100.30.1.40       iPhone     23
```

Comment: this is getting there, I should have mentioned that there's another column there, editing my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(*)` instead:

```
SELECT platform, COUNT(*) 
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform 
ORDER BY COUNT(platform) DESC
```

Comment: How will `COUNT(*)` give different results than `COUNT(platform)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the IP address as well:

```
SELECT platform, COUNT(*) 
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY platform, remote_ip_addr 
ORDER BY COUNT(platform) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by IP address to get the number of different platforms:

```
SELECT platform, COUNT(platform) 
FROM fuckedapps_dm_appdl dm 
GROUP BY remote_ip_addr 
ORDER BY COUNT(platform) DESC
```